# How do sync mobile contacts with server

Tags: java, android, chat, mqtt

I'm creating a chat app with java

I use the mqtt protocol and the mosquitto broker

I need to sync the user's contacts with the server and check if they are members

It's technically impossible to send a mobile number to the server for review
As a result,

I decided that every member of the forum should be based on his mobile number

Now I want to know if the user is in chat

I will send a message to the topic with the mobile number of that contact

And if I get it, it means being a member of the chat

And if the message is not received it means not being a member

The main problem is that the message is not received if the user is not online,
 and this is not the case

Is there a good way to sync your phone users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use last will & testament functionality - when User is disconnected an earlier prepared message is send as notification.

For keeping message from disconnected user you can set flag retain.

From HiveMqtt website:
"A retained message is a normal MQTT message with the retained flag set to true. The broker will store the last retained message and the corresponding QoS for that topic"

Comment: But my goal is detect topic is registered or user is exist in broker or not.in your way it is sending message with retain feature and cannot receive it,isn't it?

Comment: You can set up a topic  (for example named "connected devices") and subtopic (for every device) . Every device send message (let say, "on"/"off") when is conecting and disconnecting. Others client should subscribe to all subtopic ("connected device/*") to get know status of other devices